# Not sure what to do next with my follow-up question

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [batch file - TASKKILL /FI "WINDOW TITLE ..." not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253085/batch-file-taskkill-fi-window-title-not-working)

With the help I've got here I know why my `TASKKILL /FI "WINDOW TITLE ..."` DOS command is not working the way I need. However, my batch file is still not working because I now have questions about Window Titles.

Do I change the name of my post's question or create a new one?

If I should create a new one, how do I mark this one as answered?  There are no answers to upvote & accept, only helpful comments.

Comment: If you like you can ask the helpful commenters if you are allowed to create an answer using the comments. You can answer your own quesiton and later accept it. Or you can just do nothing.

Comment: Thank you George.  Please post what you said as an answer so I can mark is as correct.

Comment: @mike_yung yeah I have, I realised the irony in that as soon as I posted it.

Comment: Sorry if that came across as sarcastic.  None was intended.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*"I now have questions about Window Titles."* You now have a different question, although related, create a new question otherwise you would be changing the scope of the current question

As for marking the old question you can ask the commentators to post what they've said as an answer and then mark that as correct